# Re-write Name,CN, and DN attribute for Active Directory users with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server-2010

Toying with a Lotus Notes to Active Directory connector, I managed to change all my user's `Name`, `CN` and `distinguishedName` fields to resemble an email address. ugh.
All seems fine aside from maybe 1 utility that used cn/ldap to reference AD, but it looks bizarre in AD users and computers.

I'd like to rewrite users `name` fields as to update it back to how it used to look (This fixes `cn` and `dn` fields I see). Preferably using AD Powershell or Exchange Management shell.

When using exchange management shell and writing to the `name` field, it also rewrites the "showinaddressbook" values. (figure this must be an exchange thing, but I can't have it happen). 
Here's what I did:

```
$displayname = Get-MailUser -Identity joe.user | select -ExpandProperty Displayname

Set-MailUser -Identity joe.user -Name $displayname
```

When attempting to use AD Powershell and do something similar, it doesn't look possible to write to the name field with "set-aduser".
I'm not overly schooled in doing this. But I'd like to be able to rewrite the name field with "givenname surname" or "displayname" (preferred).
And somehow loop through all my users without affecting the "showinaddressbook" exchange attribute.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the CN by using the command below, however the CN is the name that will show in AD OU and it's same as Full Name

```
Set-ADUser $Username -PassThru | Rename-ADObject -NewName $FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you... you need to use the `Rename-ADObject` cmdlet.